# Objectify can't find entity on Datastore with Cache on

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, caching, objectify

I am trying to load an entity by id to check if it exists. If I call as below it returns null:

```
String idS = lat+lon+lang;
GeoVars response = ofy().load().type(GeoVars.class).id(idS).now(); //Always returns null
```

If I turn off the cache it returns the entitiy:

```
GeoVars response = ofy().cache(false).load().type(GeoVars.class).id(idS).now(); //Returns OK
```

And here is the GeoVars class:

```
@Entity
@Cache
public class GeoVars {
    @Id String id;
    String summary;
    String something;
    String another;
    String blabla;
    String lang;
    int day;
```

I understand that memcache is "best effort" basis but even it is not cached, it should take the entity from datastore automatically? Why does load return null?

EDIT:

When I try with safe, also returns null.

```
    try {
        response = ofy().load().type(GeoVars.class).id(idS).safe();
    } catch (com.googlecode.objectify.NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = createResponse(idS, lat, lon, lang, dayofweek);
        ofy().save().entity(response);
    }
```

Comment: What version of Objectify are you using and what happens if you change `now()` to `safe()`?

Comment: @tx802 I am using v5. I will try and inform what happens with safe() but normally I need the null value to create if it doesn't exist.

Comment: You could put the creation code inside the `catch(NotFoundException)` block.

Comment: I tried, same thing happens. You can see the edit above.

Comment: @tx802 any ideas? I am really stuck!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I forgot to put ObjectifyFilter to web.xml. Now it works all fine.